# Leaflet Layer Control, grabbing GeoJSON data from different file

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I created a Leaflet map with marketClusters, where the GeoJSON data is structued (and fetched) in a separate js-document, as a variable. See below for example.

> `var markers = [
>     {
>       "name":"test",
>       "city":"Stockholm, Sweden",
>       "market":"test",
>       "website":"<a target='_blank' href='http://test.se'>test.se</a>",
>       "lat":5.336391,
>       "lng":1.027678,`

What I want to add now is a layer control to my map where I can toggle between different nodes based on "market" in the variable "markers" (which again is located in a separate file).

As an example, I want to add 4-5 different variables for "market" and would then like to toggle between those in the layer control.

My code is based on the [leaflet.markerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin example:

```js
var map = L.map( 'map', {
  center: [10.0, 5.0],
  minZoom: 2,
  zoom: 2

});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
}).addTo( map );

var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="leaf-demo.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'leaf-demo.js', '' );

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + '../images/pin24.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: myURL + '../images/pin48.png',
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14]
});

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i )
{
  var popup = '<b>' + markers[i].name + '</b>' +
              '<br/>' + markers[i].city +
              '<br/>' + markers[i].market +
              '<br/>'+
              markers[i].website;

  var m = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
                  .bindPopup( popup );

  markerClusters.addLayer( m );
}

map.addLayer( markerClusters );
```

I'm kinda lost as how to proceed, any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your markers to cluster all together (mixing "oranges with apples"), you would probably be interested in [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup plugin](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) (see [demo](http://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup/examples/subGroup-markercluster-controlLayers-realworld.388.html)). Simply create 1 subgroup per `market` value and set their parent as your `markerClusters`.

Otherwise, you can simply create 1 Marker Cluster Group per group of markers. But clusters might overlap.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of that plugin.